how can I stop hintText misalignment?
I have a customtextfield widget.When I give a suffix as an argument.I see misalignment in hinttext.Here it is code block you can look at.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? hintText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Widget? suffixWidget;
  final Widget? suffixIconWidget;
  final String title;
  const CustomTextField(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      this.hintText,
      required this.controller,
      this.suffixWidget,
      this.suffixIconWidget});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Color(0xFF696F79)),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            child: TextFormField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              controller: controller,
              cursorColor: const Color(0xFF035762),
              onTapOutside: (event) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: hintText,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0)
                      .copyWith(left: 5),
                  focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF035762))),
                  enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  suffix: suffixWidget,
                  suffixIcon: suffixIconWidget),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I used this widget like that:
CustomTextField(
              controller: _nameController,
              title: 'Ad*',
              hintText: 'Farid Ahmadov',
              suffixWidget: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Color(0xFF8692A6),
                  )),
            ),

as you see misalignment as it shown with red line

I give true value to isDense and isCollapsed parameters of TextFormField,and give varios values to contentPadding vertically.However it did not help.

Set contentPadding null

@RobertS  it did not help Sir.In this case suffix is badly aligned

If I replace suffixWidget with suffixIconWidget then I see no issue.


Thank you so much sir,but I deliberately did not do it beace I want icon is showed when textfield is pressed.

Ok, just add FocusNode to your CustomTextField and then listen to focus state.
final focusNode = FocusNode();
focusNode.addListener(() {
setState(() {});
});
return CustomTextField(
focusNode: focusNode,
Please do not forget to dispose focusNode like this: focusNode.dispose();
suffixWidget: !focusNode.hasFocus
? null
: SizedBox(
width: 24,
height: 24,
child: IconButton(
.....)

Use suffixIconWidget instead of suffixWidget refer suffix and suffixIcon
CustomTextField(
          controller: _nameController,
          title: 'Ad*',
          hintText: 'Farid Ahmadov',
          suffixIconWidget: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Color(0xFF8692A6),
            ), // Icon
          ), // IconButton
        ),

Result- 

Thank you so much sir,but I deliberately did not do it beace I want icon is showed when textfield is pressed.
